# Running AsyncTask from Quartz.net

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, quartz.net

I have a quartz job that run periodically, and within execution I would submit a a rest api request, via HttpClient. Currently if the rest api "call" failed(for instance Bad request status code 400), it would "resend" the same api call like 2-4 times. This behavor is not "right", all i want is to log the result of rest api call, since i wouldn't want a postasync request to execute after the original trigger time.

- So this is basically the "pseudocode", I am just creating a bunch of reports via a quartz job then sending them.
- **The issue occurs when a the createreport fails, somehow the request would be "re-sent" (I am logging from within createReport function after await, and i am seeing the request resent/response received again)**
- I am pretty new to this so I am not sure if a retry mecanism is already baked into async await, or quartz itself.

```cs
class Job : IJob
{
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(index => CreateReport(index));
        try
        {
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public static async Task CreateReport(int index)
    {
        var response = await ReportApi.PostAsync($"api/createReport/...", null);
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code. quartz will not automatically run the task again because of failure.

Comment: Use a library like Polly for retry strategies. https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: My problem is that it is "retrying" on its own, I don't want it to retry, how polly would fix what I am having right now ?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally in this case you would model your model more messaging-like. You can have single job but create a trigger for each report that invokes the job, you can have the "report id/user id/ etc" as parameter to trigger job data map. This way only single report at a time will be affected of problems.

Now if your job fails, it will be retried by default. You can prohibit this by having a try-catch around you logic and in case of an error throw `JobExecutionException` which allows you set logic conditions via its properties, like `UnscheduleFiringTrigger` which allows it to stop trying again - but this is for a one shot trigger, the trigger in question will never fire again during the running schduler.

Generally I'd advice for state management (has the report been generated) in outside source like a database. Then in trigger check what's the correct action. Also like suggested in comments, retry library might allow for more fine-grained actions.